# Let $G ⊂ S_7$ be a subgroup of order 8. Then there exists $i$ such that $\sigma(i)=i.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking for the solution of the following question.

Let $G ⊂ S_7$ be a subgroup of order 8. Prove that there exists $i ∈\{1,...,7\}$ such that for any $σ ∈ G$ we have $σ(i) = i$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you consider $G$ has a group acting on $\{1,\dots,7\}$, you can decompose this set in orbits under the action of $G$:
$$\{1,\dots,7\}=A_1\sqcup \dots \sqcup A_n;$$this implies
$$7=|A_1|+\dots + |A_n|.$$
Now every orbit is in bijection with a coset of $G$:
$$A_i\cong G/G_{x_i},$$
where $x_i\in A_i$ and $G_{x_i}=\{\sigma \in G| \sigma(x_i)=x_i\}$; in particular we have
$$|A_i|=\frac{8}{|G_{x_i}|}.$$Since the sum of the cardinalities is odd, one of the $|A_i|$ must have odd cardinality. But $\frac{8}{|G_{x_i}|}$ divides $8$, so the only possible value is $1$. Thus one of the orbit is reduced to a point, which means the point is fixed by all $G$.